# vertical/horizontal asymptotes - general understanding

Tags: differential-geometry

Do vertical asymptote only exists in fractions?
My taught was yes.

Can the curve cross a vertical asymptote?
My taught was no.

Can the curve cross a horizontal asymptote?
my taught was yes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. No. For example $f(x)=\tan{x}$. It has vertical asymptotes at $x=k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}$.
2. No. Otherwise it has multiple $y$ values at one $x$ value.
3. Yes. For example $e^{-x} \sin{x}$.